# »Bitte wegtreten zu dürfen«

Tags: infinitive, grammar-identification

Als ich *Im Westen nichts Neues* von Remarque gelesen habe, ist mir ein Absatz begegnet, den ich nicht genau verstanden habe:

> Wenn  Sie  nächstens  mit 'rausgehen, werden  die  Mannschaften,  bevor  sie sterben, erst vor Sie hintreten, die Knochen zusammenreißen und zackig
>   fragen: **Bitte wegtreten zu dürfen! Bitte abkratzen zu dürfen!** Auf Leute wie Sie haben wir hier gerade gewartet."

Ich habe Probleme mit dem Verständnis der fett markierten Sätze: Was bedeuten sie? Und hat diese Grammatikform einen Namen?

Comment: In military usage, "bitte"== "ich bitte...".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ich denke dies ist reine Militärsprache. Die Soldaten bitten zackig um Erlaubnis zu sterben oder wegzugehen. In englisch würden sie etwa sagen. "Requesting permission to ... etc". Rein militärischer Telegramstil, der um Missverständnisse zu vermeiden, geschaffen wurde.

Answer (score 5):

Vollständig würde der Satz lauten "**Ich** bitte **darum**, wegtreten zu dürfen."

Ich denke, dann ist auch der Inhalt einfacher verständlich. Die Übersetzung des militärischen "Wegtreten" ist laut Leo.org *"to dismiss" (allow to leave)*.

Das darauf folgende "**Ich** bitte **darum**, abkratzen zu dürfen." soll wohl bedeuten, dass sie anstatt ums Wegtreten genauso gut um ihren Tod bitten könnten - es würde keine Rolle mehr spielen, da es sowieso darauf hinauslaufen wird, zu sterben.